# How to set config or admin bar for an app from the app itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, configuration, config

I have an app made with rails and deployed on heroku. Let's say there are 2 options for the background image- "land" and "sea".

So we could define it as a heroku level environment config, or we could define it in any controller or helper method that's relevant. But all of these are "programmatic" solutions requiring code. Even logging into the heroku dashboard still requires the admin to leave the app itself, sign in on a separate platform, and then make changes.

I want to build a front end GUI for the admin to change the background image using this variable that's in-app. So the admin never has to leave the app or know any code.

But how do you do this? Btw I realize heroku has a platform API, but I'm looking for another rails only solution if possible because this background image var isn't at the same level of importance as actual config variables that I want to keep on heroku (ie if it's not set- there just will be no image, rather than some kind of app error)

Comment: Maybe the simplest way is to use a model. I don’t think you can write local flies.

Comment: It's just such a random collection of data. I could have a model and db with the attributes: 'key' & 'value'- but this seems overdone?

Answer (score 0):

The way I accomplish this is to have the setting in some model somewhere, probably using an enum. So for example, my model could be called Settings.

```
class Setting < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  enum background-setting: { land: 0, sea: 1 }
```

Then in your view, simply do a if-else and set the view to display whatever div you want.

```
<% if @something.background-setting == "land" %>
  <div class="land-bg"></div>
<% else %>
  <div class="sea-bg"></div>
<% end %>
```

Then simply specify the bg images in your css. I suppose it's easier to explain using a more practical example from my own work, let's say I have two types of users (regular and publisher). I can put use the user's type from the database as my determinant for how to display a different background between the two. So instead of `@something.background-setting`, I would be calling on `@user.usertype` or `@user.role`.

Comment: The only reason I'm looking else

Comment: The only reason this is less ideal for me is because I have a bunch of random variables like this. Some of which depends on user some of which do not (even though they are settable by the admin). I've though about having a dedicated model with attributes just to store all these random variables but it seems weird to use a db table that way